# How to send packet in a decentralized token ring?

Tags: c#, network-programming

I need to realize fully decentralized Token Ring protocol application for my course work.
So, here it is:

> Every launched app (node) has own ID, and the current node is server for previous node and client for next node in ring (so, there are 2 parallel tcp-connections between nodes). User inputs the port of current node, IP-address and port one of other server-nodes, data for packet (token), current ID of node and destination ID

I don't know how to send received token to next node in ring. And how can I realize 2 tcp-connections? I tried to start 2 threads for every node (1 for server function and 1 for client), but I think this is wrong way.

Also I implemented 2 functions for «client» and «server».

Server:

```
/*some code...*/
if (server.Pending()) {
    /*...some code*/
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    int i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    if (i > 0) {

        recv = /*some code*/
        Invoke(AddTextDelegateS, "Someone connected. Waiting for mine token...");
        answer = /*some code*/

        //extracting destination node ID
        int dest_new = /*some code*/
        dest_id = dest_new;

        if (current_id == dest_id) {
            // OK, token received right node
            Invoke(AddTextDelegateC, "Node with id " + current_id.ToString() + " recieved token with data:");
            Invoke(AddTextDelegateC, recv);

        } else {

            //in this part I'm trying to send <------------
            Thread tmp_thread = new Thread(startclient);
            tmp_thread.IsBackground = true;
            tmp_thread.Start();
            //

        }
        byte[] answer_bytes = /*some code */
        stream.Write(answer_bytes, 0, answer_bytes.Length);
        /*....*/
```